# Recursion for traversing multiple divs in order to find select tag using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, recursion

I'm lookin to solve one problem using recursions but I'm
unfortunately very bad at it. Do u guys have any idea how would this recursion look like.
This is just a made up example because those elements after main-div
class are hidden and I would wanna know how to traverse this entire div
tree to search for a select tag using selenium.
I'm very bad at recursions so would appriciate any help or ideas.

```
<div class="main-div">
<div>
    <div><p>Some text1</p></div>
    <div><p>Some text2</p></div>
    <div><p>Some text3</p></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div><p>Some text4</p></div>
    <div>
    <p>Some text5</p>
    <div><p>Div containing my select file<p>
    <select>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know that I have to use
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('main-div')
to search for that specific element. Afterwards I think that I should do
smth lik for loop to find every element smth like:

```
for record in main_div:
new_to_search = record.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
##calling my recursive function
myFunction(new_to_search, selectTag)
```

So here I'm stuck...

Edit:

What do u guys think about this approach. Will this cover every element ?

```
def myFunc(element):
print(len(element))
for record in element:
    print(element)
    checkRecord(record)
    new_div_element = record.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div')
    if(len(new_div_element) > 0):
     myFunc(new_div_element)
def checkRecord(element):
 select = element.find_elements_by_tag_name('select')
 if(len(select) > 0):
  print("U've found ur select tag")
argument = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('main_div')
#calling my recursive function
myFunc(argument)
```

Comment: I'm happy to help if i can but i'm not sure what you need here. You can use an xpath identifier to get all the `select` elements and then iterate as you need... `//div/div/select` or `//div//select` will pull everything out from your pattern. Reckon you can have a go at explaining what you need with a bigger (actual) html example?

Comment: I know I can finish this by xpath tag, but imagine there is no visible tree structure and u have to iterate over every thing inside the main div(that one with the class 'main-div) and traverse each of its child elements to look for a select tag. The only thing we know is <div class = "main-div"></div> and don't know anything bout his child elements.

Comment: the driver can know everything about the child elements once they are in the DOM.  What are you trying to do exactly?  Are you searching for a specific condition?

Comment: in general, though, and more to your question, recursion isn't possible if you do any driver actions that affect the DOM without starting a new thread/driver for each recursion.  (you could open tabs but the order of your actions is going to get pretty whacky...)  If you are only finding things, you'd be good, but recursion isn't necessary then.  You have the whole DOM already and XPATH is great for finding what you want.

Comment: Now it's clear to me that recursions can make some serious problem like finding different length of elements to be found. All of this can be prevented by using xpath so ty for the clear explanation.